# Event Modifier on Quasar QSelect Remove Event

Tags: events, quasar, modifier

I want to remove an option from selection conditionally.. I tried to use @remove event but I couldn't stop remove event before my check... I want to do something below;

```
<q-select @remove.stop="isItRemovable"></q-select>
.
.
.
methods: {
  isItRemovable(option) {
    if (option.value.name === 'yes removable') {
        remove
    } else {
       show not removable warning
    }
  }
}
```

how can i do this? than you.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and figured out a dirty solution

```js
function onRemove(details) {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    tags.value.splice(details.index, 0, details.value as never);
  }, 1) // yes this is very dirty, but it seems to me there is no better way with current Quasar API
}
```

Where `tags` is your `ref` used as `v-model` and this function is used as event callback: `@remove="onRemove"`.
This will prevent any item removal, but of course you can add any conditions. Side effect: element blinks for a millisecond.